# How to use Endpoints and Schema

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, on-chain, smart-contract

I doing the PPP but Lars does not cover Endpoints or schema declarations in sufficient detail. I imagine that this is a problem that Plutus devs must overcome, but I cannot find suitable documentation on this topic.

Can you please explain how to use Endpoints and Schema in a contract, and possibly provide a few links for further reading.

Thankyou.